# Custom Page Create

Tags: theming, path-aliases

I create page--hospital.tpl.php file. To call this page, then I create Basic Page and Page title is "Hospital".
I provided on the Menu Link and I typed "hospital" in URL path alias.
Then, Save the file.

The problem is that when I click on the "Hospital" menu link it only shows the basic page content and it **doesn't show up** my page--hospital.tpl.php file.
Please,help me !

Thanks.

Comment: I also renamed the page--hospital.tpl.php page into "page--node--7.tpl.php". However, it also has a problem because giving the nodeid to the pagename makes not flexible. If I deploy in other PC, and create Basic Page , then it does not same the nodeid. I also don't want to export my database and import to other database

Comment: In that case I suggest you create a new content type that has similar fields to basic page. Then you override node.tpl.php with node--type.tpl.php where type is the machine name of your new content type. This will then be exportable in a flexible way. Also look at 'Add a page.tpl.php depending on content type.' section on [doc page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) on how to do custom theme suggestions via a preprocess function.

Answer (score 4):

To understand how to use Theme Hook Suggestions, please refer to the documentation at: [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

> **node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php**
>
> base template: node.tpl.php
>
> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from
>   the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most
>   specific template it finds:
>
> node--nodeid.tpl.php
>
> node--type.tpl.php
>
> node.tpl.php
>
> **page--[front|internal/path].tpl.php**
>
> base template: page.tpl.php
>
> The suggestions are numerous. The one that takes precedence is for the
>   front page. The rest are based on the internal path of the current
>   page. Do not confuse the internal path to path aliases which are not
>   accounted for. Keep in mind that the commonly-used Pathauto module
>   uses path aliases.
>
> The front page can be set at "Administration > Configuration > System
>
> > Site information." In Drupal 6, at "Administrator > Site configuration > Site information." Anything set there will trigger the
> >     suggestion of "page--front.tpl.php" for it.
>
> The list of suggested template files is in order of specificity based
>   on internal paths. One suggestion is made for every element of the
>   current path, though numeric elements are not carried to subsequent
>   suggestions. For example, "http://www.example.com/node/1/edit" would
>   result in the following suggestions:
>
> 1. page--node--edit.tpl.php
> 2. page--node--1.tpl.php
> 3. page--node.tpl.php
> 4. page.tpl.php

It can be done in a variety of ways (at the page level as well). You can also provide your own suggestions in a preprocess function.

In your case you have not defined a new content type, but have used the Basic Page type, and you want to do it for a single page only. You therefore need to get the node id of your page, and then override as follows:

```
node--nodeid.tpl.php
```

or

```
page--node--nodeid.tpl.php
```

In your case, as you indicated that you wish to override the page.tpl.php file, it will be the latter.